# Canceled SSHFS (fuse) mount - cannot remove directory

Tags: ssh, mount, sshfs, fuse

I tried to mount an SSHFS directory locally, failed, and now I cannot use my original directory anymore.

Following a tutorial, I just installed the `sshfs` package, executed `sudo modprobe fuse`, and then created a local directory `remote` where I would like to mount the remote directory.

I then ran `sshfs -o idmap=user "myuser@<host>:/home/myuser" remote`, as indicated in the tutorial, but my connection was slow so I Ctrl+C'd it.

Now, if I do `ls` on its parent directory, I obtain this entry (as an example, I left the next entry as well):

```
...
d?????????  ? ?      ?      ?    ?            remote
drwxr-xr-x  2 myuser myuser 4096 Mar 13 11:02 Videos
...
```

If I try `cd remote`, I get:

`cd: transport endpoint is not connected: remote`

Trying to remove the directory does not succeed:

`rmdir: failed to remove ‘remote’: Device or resource busy`

How can I get rid of this directory, preferably without having to reboot?

Comment: Did you try to reboot?

Comment: I'd like to avoid that if possible (updated question).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
fusermount -u remote
```

to unmount the mount point.

Answer (score 2):

umount -l remote

```
   -l     Lazy  unmount.  Detach  the  filesystem from the filesystem hierarchy now, and cleanup all references to the filesystem as
          soon as it is not busy anymore.  (Requires kernel 2.4.11 or later.)
```